# nexus set ip default next hop not workign

Tags: cisco-nx-os

i have a N3K-3064pq-10gx and i have a pbr for some of my VLANs with set IP default next-hop 1.2.3.4 and have a static route for default route in my switch but the problem here is my traffic routes have been matched with this static route and does not use the assigned PBR, is there any way to exclude default static route from pbr ? so my internal routing will keep in nexus but other traffic will match with his pbr.
here is my route map config
route-map pbr-tun, permit, sequence 10

```
  Match clauses:
    ip address (access-lists): pbr-tun
  Set clauses:
    ip next-hop 172.16.17.91
```

here is my vlan config

```
interface Vlan3250
  description 3250-VLAN3250
  no shutdown
  no ip redirects
  ip address x/27
  ip address x/28 secondary
  ip policy route-map pbr-tun
```

here is my default route config

```
show ip route 0.0.0.0/0 detail
IP Route Table for VRF "default"
'*' denotes best ucast next-hop
'**' denotes best mcast next-hop
'[x/y]' denotes [preference/metric]
'%<string>' in via output denotes VRF <string>

0.0.0.0/0, ubest/mbest: 1/0
    *via y, [1/0], 1w6d, static
         recursive next hop: y/32
```

thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full switch configuration.

Comment: i have many full config and i do nto want share it with others! i just add important config!

Comment: There is a lot of the missing configuration that could affect this. We cannot help if you do not give us what we need to help. For example, how does the switch know where the `172.16.17.91` next hop is? You simply need to give us the full configuration, otherwise we can only guess, which is off-topic here.